# probability, once fair die , 3 players.

Tags: probability

I have this problem, three players A,B and C, takes turnes rolling a fair die, the first to roll and odd prime is the winner. If A goes first, then B, then A and so forth, what is each player probability of winning expressed as a percent?

I tried with two players, and I took into consideration that it will be the 2/6+4/6(p(a)-1) but this if the player B doesn't get a prime odd and A does it at the second try. How I can express it with 3 players and most importantly no knowing in which turn a player will win?

Answer (score 1):

one of them must win so $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$

also

$$P(B) = P(A)\times P(A\text{ does not win on first roll}) $$

$$P(C) = P(A)\times P(\text{ neither A nor B win on first roll}) $$
So

$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=P(A) ( 1+ \frac 23 +\frac 49)$$

Comment: WW1 thanks for you comment, still my problem is to find the probability of player, could I do it, based on how you posed the problem using a system of 3 equations?

Comment: NYN the three equations are $P(A)\times \frac{19}{9}=1, \;P(B)=\frac 23 P(A) \; , P(C)=\frac 49 P(A)$

Answer (score 1):

Let P be the event the number tossed is an odd prime, and N the event it is not.  Then the toss patterns for which A wins are:

P, NNNP, NNNNNNP, NNNNNNNNNP, and so on.

These have probabilities:

$1/3$; $(2/3)^3(1/3)$; $(2/3)^6(1/3)$; $(2/3)^9(1/3)$; and so on.

For the probability A ultimately wins, add up. We have a geometric series with first term $1/3$ and common ratio $(2/3)^3$. The sum, by the usual formula, is
$$\frac{1/3}{1-(2/3)^3}.$$
This can be simplified to $\frac{9}{19}$.

For the probability B wins, the relevant probabilities to add are

$(2/3)(1/3)$; $(2/3)^4(1/3)$; $(2/3)^7(1/3)$; $(2/3)^{10}(1/3)$, and so on. Add up. Again a geometric series, with each term $2/3$ times the series for A winning.

The sum is therefore $6/19$.  A similar argument shows that the probability C wins is $4/19$.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I think I thought the generic term of that sum before.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Andre, I am not sure to understand what you meant by Again a geometric series, with each term 2/3 times the series for A winning. First , what is the ratio? and if A is winning B is not playing? The event are independents.

Comment: The terms for B winning the game are written in the answer. We are finding the sum $(2/3)(1/3)+(2/3)^4(1/3)+(2/3)^7(1/3)+\cdots$. This is a geometric series first term $(2/3)(1/3)$, common ratio $(2/3)^3$. We can calculate the sum using the familiar formula. There is no need to notice that this series is $2/3$ times the series for A winning, noticing just saves time in computing the sum.